# Textview Color is not changed by style

Tags: android, layout, colors, styles, android-theme

I do have the problem that since the last update of Android Studio and the SDK to:

Installed SDK:
All including rev. 25.1.2

Android Studio:
Android Studio 2.0 Build #AI-143.2739321, built on April 5, 2016 JRE: 1.7.0_80-b15 amd64

I cannot change the color of the TextView anymore by style ....

build min sdk is:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 22
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

The TextView "dashboardGridItemTitleTextView" does always contain a default color ("white")

The Layout of the the parent item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dashboardGridItemImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/textmessage_128"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dashboardGridItemTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/title_load_containers"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badgeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_badge"
        android:minWidth="10dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Nothing special I know and the style which is used for the application. I do have theme switch so dont care about the dark theme:

```
<resources>

    <style name="CommonAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CommonActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/buttonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/dialogTheme</item>
        <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/MarginlessImageButton</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
        <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/textViewStyle</item>

        <item name="theme_dependent_list_item_background">@drawable/company_list_bg</item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_list_item_background_highlighted">
            @drawable/company_list_bg_highlighted
        </item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_default_button">@drawable/button_rounded_corner</item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_text_color">@color/black</item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_text_color_highlighted">@color/black</item>

        <item name="theme_dependent_button_rounded_corner_green">
            @drawable/button_rounded_corner_green
        </item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_button_rounded_corner_red">@drawable/button_rounded_corner_red
        </item>
    </style>

    <style name="CommonAppThemeDark" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CommonActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/buttonStyleDark</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/dialogThemeDark</item>

        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/textViewStyleDark</item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_list_item_background">@drawable/company_list_bg_dark</item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_list_item_background_highlighted">
            @drawable/company_list_bg_dark_highlighted
        </item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_default_button">@drawable/button_rounded_corner_dark</item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_text_color">@drawable/company_list_text_dark</item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_text_color_highlighted">@drawable/company_list_text_dark</item>

        <item name="theme_dependent_button_rounded_corner_green">
            @drawable/button_rounded_corner_green_dark
        </item>
        <item name="theme_dependent_button_rounded_corner_red">
            @drawable/button_rounded_corner_red_dark
        </item>
    </style>

    <style name="CommonActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/darkGreen</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showCustom</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/titleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="titleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ListViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/company_list_bg</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/company_list_bg</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/company_list_bg</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/company_list_bg</item>
    </style>

    <style name="buttonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_rounded_corner</item>
    </style>

    <style name="buttonStyleDark" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_rounded_corner_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_text_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MarginlessImageButton" parent="android:Widget.ImageButton">
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>

    <!-- TextView -->

    <style name="textViewStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:color">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/commonTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="commonTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:color">@color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textViewStyleDark" parent="android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/commonTextAppearanceDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="commonTextAppearanceDark" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Alert / Dialog Theme|Style -->

    <style name="dialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/DialogButtonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="dialogThemeDark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
        <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyleDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/DialogButtonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyleDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogButtonBarStyle">
        <item name="android:showDividers"></item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_rounded_corner</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogButtonStyleDark" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_rounded_corner_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_text_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I tried anything to get this fixed .... But I does not work. Can anybody help this newbie? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I found this in the build log :

2016-04-12 10:19:06,933 [7270100]   WARN - rendering.ConfigurationMatcher - 'default' is not a best match for any device/locale combination for file://C:/Sources/iApps/iMulco/app/src/main/res/layout/grid_item_dashboard.xml.
Displaying it with
  , , , Left To Right, sw384dp, w384dp, h640dp, Normal Screen, Short screen aspect ratio, Not Round screen, Portrait Orientation, Normal, Day time, X-High Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Hidden navigation, No navigation, Screen resolution 1280x768, API Level 24

Comment: why you are using style ? simple put color text in XML ?

Comment: No need to do with style ,you can directly do that things in two ways ,give text color inside xml files or set color to your textview inside your java file like textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR));

Comment: Can you even read ? :

I do have theme switch so dont care about the dark theme:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have values-v21 folder and there text color is white(or not changed)